# How to redirect one url to another url in Kong Workspace?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I have a service in Kong. Say I have a service with url "abc.com". When the user enters the url in a browser, it has to rediect to "xyz.com/home". How to do this in Kong workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Set kong's service target to xyz.com, and the service path is /home.
And the route path is '/'; Make sure you kong listening the abc.com.